# Standard error of the sampling distribution and standard deviation

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I wanted to verify that the standard error of the sampling distribution = $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$

```
 USAccDeaths
```

I used this above dataset from R Datasets Package

**population parameters**

```
  mean(USAccDeaths)
  sd(USAccDeaths)
```

**Creating a Sampling Distribution**

```
  n=40 #Sample size.
  nruns=10000 # Number of samples to draw.
  store=double(nruns)
  for (run in 1:nruns){
  samp=sample(USAccDeaths,n)
  store[run]=mean(samp)}
```

My question is shouldn't

```
        sd(USAccDeaths)/sqrt(n) be approximately equal to sd(store)
```

when I run this I get values that are completely different

Comment: what is the procedure you adopted for sd(store) ? Also ondicate your summary of results?

Comment: @subhashc.davar, I considered sd(store) to be the standard error of the sampling distribution                                                                         
results-                                                                                             
`sd(store)
[1] 101.5435  and                                                                                                                    
     sd(USAccDeaths)/sqrt(n)
    [1] 151.434`

Comment: How do you compute sd (store)

Comment: explain briefly background of your problem and the data you are worlking on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sampling with replacement

Try this

```
n_samples=1000
n_sample=40
my.samples<-sample(USAccDeaths,n_sample*n_samples,replace=TRUE)
dim(my.samples)<-c(n_sample,n_samples)
store<-apply(my.samples,2,mean)
sd(store)
```

> 151.0806

```
sd(USAccDeaths)/sqrt(n_sample)
```

> 151.434

### Sampling without replacement

I you do not sample with replacement, than you should use the following finite correction
$$\sigma_{\bar{X}}=\sqrt{\frac{N-n}{n-1}}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$

As you can see

```
sqrt((length(USAccDeaths)-n_sample)/(length(USAccDeaths)-1))*sd(USAccDeaths)/sqrt(n_sample)
```

> 101.6645

Which matches the result of your code, where you sampled without replacement

```
for(run in 1:n_samples){store[run]=mean(sample(USAccDeaths,n_sample))}
sd(store)
```

> 101.5435

Comment: should I do do this then `samp=sample(USAccDeaths,n,nruns)`

Comment: I added an explanation of why your approach produced an error. I also added how to correct your approach, to produce the same result as mine. You sampled without replacement, while assuming that you sampled with replacement. Please see the edited code and tell me if you understand now.

Comment: yes, I was able to verify using my code that `sd(store)` =`sd(USAccDeaths)/sqrt(n)` when `samp=sample(USAccDeaths,n,replace=TRUE)`. I guess when I was sampling without replacement, I was getting a standard error consistently smaller than `sd(USAccDeaths)/sqrt(n)`